# Windows Forms Custom DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am not very experienced with Windows Forms and am not pretty sure how I should tackle with this task the best way possible. I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class VariableMapping
{
    private string variableName;
    private string variableText;
    private string variableSelector;

    public VariableMapping(string variableName, string variableText, string variableSelector)
    {
        this.VariableName = variableName;
        this.VariableText = variableText;
        this.VariableSelector = variableSelector;
    }

    public string VariableName
    {
        get { return this.variableName; }
        set { this.variableName = value; }
    }

    public string VariableText
    {
        get { return this.variableText; }
        set { this.variableText = value; }
    }

    public string VariableSelector
    {
        get { return this.variableSelector; }
        set { this.variableSelector = value; }
    }
}
```

I want to create a DataGridView which should be bound to a number of elements of type VariableMapping in a list. However, I want only 1 of the properties(VariableText) of every instance to be shown in the DataGridView but I want to be able to address the whole object through the DataGrid when I need to. I also need to add 2 more custom columns: a ComboBox with predefined values and a NumberBox.

It might seem a really simple task but I'm trully unexperienced in WinForms and couldn't find a solution I can use already. Thank you!

**Edit**: I am trying something like this but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
public partial class MappingTable : Form
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

    public MappingTable(List<VariableMapping> variableMappings)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var colors = new List<string>() { "@color_k1", "@color_k2", "@color_s1" };

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = variableMappings;

        DataGridViewColumn titleColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
        titleColumn.DataPropertyName = "VariableText";
        titleColumn.HeaderText = "Variable";
        titleColumn.Name = "Variable*";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(titleColumn);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colorsColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        colorsColumn.DataSource = colors;
        colorsColumn.HeaderText = "Color";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colorsColumn);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn opacityColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        opacityColumn.HeaderText = "Opacity";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(opacityColumn);

        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        this.AutoSize = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are setting `DataSource` of `DataGridView` using code, you can set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false and just add the columns which you want using `DataGridView.Columns.Add`. If you are using `Designer` you can use `Columns` collection to manage what columns you want.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I editted the post by pasting the code I'm currently trying to go with. Can you please point out what am I missing?

Comment: *it doesn't seem to work properly*  is not a suitable problem description. From what I see, it adds the columns which you need. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Off-topic, but `DataGridViewColumn`  should be `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.